# How many collections of subsets of {1,2,...,n} are closed under the superset operation?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Say that I have the set $[n] = \{1,2,...,n\}$ and a collection $\mathcal{C} = \{ S_1, S_2, ..., S_k \}$ of subsets of $[n]$.  Say that $\mathcal{C}$ is *valid* if it is closed under the superset operation; i.e., if $(S \in \mathcal{C} \wedge S \subseteq S' \subseteq [n]) \implies S' \in \mathcal{C}$.  How many valid collections $\mathcal{C}$ are there, as a function of $n$?

Without the requirement to be closed under superset, the question is easier.  There are $2^n$ subsets of $[n]$, and so there are $2^{2^n}$ ways to choose which of them belong to the collection.  But not all collections are valid; for instance, if $n=2$, the valid collections are

$\mathcal{C} = \{ \emptyset, \{ 1 \} , \{ 2 \}, \{ 1,2 \} \}$,

$\mathcal{C} = \{ \{ 1 \} , \{ 2 \}, \{ 1,2 \} \}$,

$\mathcal{C} = \{ \{ 1 \}, \{ 1,2 \} \}$,

$\mathcal{C} = \{ \{ 2 \}, \{ 1,2 \} \}$,

$\mathcal{C} = \{ \{ 1,2 \} \}$, and

$\mathcal{C} = \{ \}$.

So rather than the answer being $2^{2^2} = 16$, there are only 6 valid collections.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Such a set is uniquely determined by its minimal members which form an *antichain*. The first few values and some links are [A000372](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A000372) in the OEIS

Comment: It seems these are called <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number">Dedekind numbers</a>.  Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, the last comment did not parse the link correctly: they are called Dedekind numbers, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number

Comment: Thanks again Aaron.  Here is the paper that motivated this question: http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3493.  The relevant part is Proposition 4.3.  I added an acknowledgement to you for your help.

Answer (score 15):

This is a famous problem known as the "Dedekind Problem", and it was posed by Dedekind in 1897. The [Wikipedea article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number) has some information.
There have been remarkable progress on understanding the asymptotic value of M(n) the number of antichains of sets from {1,2,...,n}. (This [paper of Kleitman](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-021-03/S0002-9939-1969-0241334-6/S0002-9939-1969-0241334-6.pdf) gives some of the history, and [this paper by Kahn](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%253A%252F%252Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%252Fviewdoc%252Fdownload%253Fdoi%253D10.1.1.103.1883%2526rep%253Drep1%2526type%253Dpdf&rct=j&q=dedekind%2520problem%2520kahn&ei=TOsiTtTFOMma-waiuoyrAw&usg=AFQjCNF6ORU-UmN92pZRFwMHss1iSyAJgQ) gives an updated history.) While $2^{{n}\choose {n/2}}$ is an obvious lower bound there is a beatiful 1966 proof by Hansel for the upperbound $3^{{n}\choose {n/2}}$.

Kleitman & Markowsky (1975). gave the asymptotic behavior of $\log M(n)$. They showed that $log M(n)$ behave asumptotically like ${{n} \choose {n/2}}$. [The paper by Kahn](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%253A%252F%252Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%252Fviewdoc%252Fdownload%253Fdoi%253D10.1.1.103.1883%2526rep%253Drep1%2526type%253Dpdf&rct=j&q=dedekind%2520problem%2520kahn&ei=TOsiTtTFOMma-waiuoyrAw&usg=AFQjCNF6ORU-UmN92pZRFwMHss1iSyAJgQ) that we already mentioned gives a simpler entropy based proof.

Amazingly, the asymptotic behavior of M(n) itself was discovered as well.
in 1981, Korshunov , using an extremely complicated approach, gave
asymptotics for M(n) itself. Simpler, though still difficult, arguments for Korshunov's
and some related results were later given by Sapozhenko. (See eg [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dedekinds-functionals-Dedekinda-granichnykh-funktsionalov/dp/5922111175).)
Sapozhenko's method turned out to be very important, e.g., in the result by [Galvin and Kahn](http://www.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/phasetransition.pdf) on the threshold behavior of the d-dimensional hard core model.